# Math shortcut for getting KBps from bytes and ms

Tags: javascript, math

Does this math make sense?  I have X number of bytes and Y number of milliseconds and I want to get KBps.

I know that I can obviously convert bytes to KB and ms to seconds and then divide, but isn't this correct too?

`kilobytes / seconds =  bytes / milliseconds`

due to the units?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if you think of a kilobyte as 1000 bytes, or 1024 bytes. A second is 1000 milliseconds, so if the former, then you're fine. If the later, then no - you need to do the full calculation.

Opinions on Kb vs KB (Kilobyte vs Kibibyte) are varied and heated. It's really just a choice, and if you're displaying things for (e.g.) storage, 1000 bytes in a kilobyte is fine.

Comment: yea, that's what's so confusing. The prefix 'kilo' implies 1000, but when applied to bytes, it's 1024 because of base 2.  It's hard when to know when it matters and when it doesn't

Comment: The kibi- abbreviation is “Ki”, not “K”, so a kibibyte would be “KiB”.

Comment: @jugg1es: As formally defined, “kilo” has always meant 1000 and never 1024. Electronics companies using it for thousands of bits and for thousands in disk sizes were correct. “KBps” would be [kilobytes per second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Kilobyte_per_second), but I see “Kbps” used more frequently, for [kilobits per second](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units#Kilobit_per_second), both in units of 1000.